# ASPX Page 'Could not load type' Error

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I have an .aspx page, we’ll call it Data.aspx, and it is going to use an ajax request to retrieve a response from a function called GenerateDocument in another .aspx page in the project, we’ll call this Document.aspx. It submits its ajax request, but the request fails, and I’m trying to decipher if it has to do with my page directives on Document.aspx. The entirety of the content on Document.aspx is this (it is not meant to generate a page, only generate documents based on data passed to it):

```
<%@ Page Language="vb" AutoEventWireup="false" CodeBehind="Document.aspx.vb" Inherits="NameSpace.Document" %>
```

In Document.aspx.vb, we have:

```
Public Class Document
    Inherits Generic.WebPage
    <System.Web.Services.WebMethod()> _
    Public Shared Function GenerateDocument
        ‘Process data and return as document
    End Function
End Class
```

(There's more than just this; there's also a page load function, etc, but this is the relevant function I'm trying to hit.)

With this configuration, the error we get is complaining about `‘Could not load type NameSpace.Document’`

I didn't think I should have to use a namespace that the class does not seem to be contained within, so I tried just saying `Inherits="Document"`, but with the same error loading type message coming back.

I am building the project after I make fixes and getting no build errors, but if I try and change the CodeBehind to a CodeFile attribute, I get runtime compilation errors instead of type errors (I am tracking this through Fiddler).

This seems like it's probably an obvious issue where the function is just not being hit, but I can't seem to parse it. Any help? Thanks.

Comment: Try this :- `Inherits="NameSpace.Document"` Because `Inherits` attribute tells the page directive which class it should use from page behind cz a namespace can contain multiple class.

Comment: If it's not meant to generate a page, you should use a generic handler (.ashx).

Comment: I mistyped the code. It was indeed using a namespace with the name of the class at the end. If I use just the class name in the Inherits, it gives the same error: `Could not load type 'Document'`

Comment: Should you not have something like this in your code behind:
Partial Public Class Document
    Inherits System.Web.UI.Page

Comment: Generic.WebPage, which my class inherits, inherits System.Web.UI.Page.

Comment: As suggested above you should probably use a Handler (.ashx) file, if you're not rendering anything to the screen from that page itself, makes more sense to use a handler.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out the issue. Thanks to all those who responded!

The problem was that while the files were all in the proper directory, one was not added to the project within the solution, and despite the references being in order (Inherits I left pointing to a namespace the class inherited from, plus the class), the program was not finding them at run time. This became apparent when I tried using CodeFile and got compilation errors and realized that it simply did not know what class to point to.

TL;DR - I added the .aspx file to the project and the whole thing worked fine.